# Ubuntu 18.04 Triple Monitor setup with Unity doesn't display 3rd monitor

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors

I'm having some weird issue with Unity in 18.04.1. The system detects all three screens. However, the third screen is just a black screen, for the most part. What's strange here is the cursor shows up on the third monitor. In fact, the cursor is even aware of what would be there. It's the typing cursor instead of the pointing cursor (see the red box I drew around the cursor in the second image). When I use the Screenshot tool to get a screenshot that spans both monitors, it shows up correctly.

What could cause something like this?
[image: screenshot]

[image: picture]

[image: settings]